# How to add only "Add to Cart" Button in a view

Tags: views, commerce

I have a view with all my product. My view display is TABLE. I'll want add a column where insert only "Add to Cart" button.

How can i do it?

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding fields, just add **Add to Cart Form** field in the view.
Attaching my view image just for your reference.

[image]

Comment: Its Ok. But, with this option i show pricing attributes too. I want only the button. where am I wrong?

Comment: That field gives only button for "Add to Cart". Did you try it?

Comment: I have upload an image of my view. My product reference field is in a fieldcollection field. I have another problem too: In my view(preview) show all selected field, but in page display i see only title view.

Comment: Sorry, I tried at my side, but couldn't reproduce your problem.